# Solving $f'(x)=f(x)f(-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think it is connected to the logistic differential equation,

$$f(x)=f(x)(1-f(x))$$

Because the logistic function has the property that $f(-x)=1-f(x)$.

Perhaps these differential equations are equivalent? I'm not really sure. T

This is not for school, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it must be that $f'(-x) = f(-x) f(x) = f'(x)$ also, which means that $f(x)$ is an odd function *plus a constant* $f_0$. That is, $f(-x) = f_0 - f(x)$ and so we have the equivalent differential equation $f'(x) = f(x) (f_0 - f(x))$, i.e. recover the Logistic equation.

Edit: Fixed basic error (eek), thanks Ninad.

Comment: Your final $f$ contradicts your first assumption that $f$ must be odd. The logical error is assuming that the antiderivative of an even function must be an odd one, which is not correct.

Comment: Couldn't $f$ be an odd function *plus a constant*?

Comment: @Hans that would be the best way to fix this, then the real differential equation simplifies to $$f'=f(f_0-f)$$ so  OP was on the money about the relationship to the logistical differential equation.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'll accept an answer that reflects the conclusion of these comments.